# How can I find the number of days between two Date objects in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, date

How can I find the number of days between two Date objects?

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Subtract the beginning date from the end date:

```
endDate - beginDate
```

Comment: think you mean subtract the begin date from the end date :)

Comment: note: if you are using Wirble in irb (to colorize the output) the rational number will have a 1 concatenated to the end. yikes! you may want to use to_i to convert the result to an integer

Comment: If you have a `DateTime` object, be sure to convert to `Date` first, otherwise it returns number of seconds (I guess).

Comment: also note subtracting two `Date` objects gives you a `Rational` that you may need to typecast into an integer, as with `(endDate - beginDate).to_i`

Comment: another useful method is: `(endDate.to_date - beginDate.to_date).to_i`

Comment: if you want to know exact days then divide with 86400 seconds

Answer (score 119):

```
irb(main):005:0> a = Date.parse("12/1/2010")
=> #<Date: 4911063/2,0,2299161>

irb(main):007:0> b = Date.parse("12/21/2010")
=> #<Date: 4911103/2,0,2299161>

irb(main):016:0> c = b.mjd - a.mjd
=> 20
```

This uses a [Modified Julian Day Number](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-mjd).

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day):

> The Julian date (JD) is the interval of time in days and fractions of a day since January 1, 4713 BC Greenwich noon, Julian proleptic calendar.

Answer (score 60):

This may have changed in Ruby 2.0

When I do this I get a fraction. For example on the console (either irb or rails c)

```
2.0.0-p195 :005 > require 'date'
 => true 
2.0.0-p195 :006 >  a_date = Date.parse("25/12/2013")
 => #<Date: 2013-12-25 ((2456652j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
2.0.0-p195 :007 >  b_date = Date.parse("10/12/2013")
 => #<Date: 2013-12-10 ((2456637j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
2.0.0-p195 :008 > a_date-b_date
 => (15/1)
```

Of course, casting to an int give the expected result

```
2.0.0-p195 :009 > (a_date-b_date).to_i
 => 15
```

This also works for DateTime objects, but you have to take into consideration seconds, such as this example

```
2.0.0-p195 :017 >   a_date_time = DateTime.now
 => #<DateTime: 2013-12-31T12:23:03-08:00 ((2456658j,73383s,725757000n),-28800s,2299161j)> 
2.0.0-p195 :018 > b_date_time = DateTime.now-20
 => #<DateTime: 2013-12-11T12:23:06-08:00 ((2456638j,73386s,69998000n),-28800s,2299161j)> 
2.0.0-p195 :019 > a_date_time - b_date_time
 => (1727997655759/86400000000) 
2.0.0-p195 :020 > (a_date_time - b_date_time).to_i
 => 19 
2.0.0-p195 :021 > c_date_time = a_date_time-20
 => #<DateTime: 2013-12-11T12:23:03-08:00 ((2456638j,73383s,725757000n),-28800s,2299161j)> 
2.0.0-p195 :022 > a_date_time - c_date_time
 => (20/1) 
2.0.0-p195 :023 > (a_date_time - c_date_time).to_i
 => 20
```

Answer (score 32):

In Ruby 2.1.3 things have changed:

```
> endDate = Date.new(2014, 1, 2)
 => #<Date: 2014-01-02 ((2456660j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
> beginDate = Date.new(2014, 1, 1)
 => #<Date: 2014-01-01 ((2456659j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
> days = endDate - beginDate
 => (1/1) 
> days.class
 => Rational 
> days.to_i
 => 1
```

Answer (score 30):

How about this?

```
(beginDate...endDate).count
```

The Range is a set of unique serials.
And `...` is an exclusive Range literal.

So `beginDate..(endDate - 1)` is same. Except is not.

In case when **beginDate** equals **endDate**, first element will be excluded because of uniqueness and `...` will exclude last one. So if we want to `.count` dates between today and today it will return 0.

Comment: This is a very good answer, if the beginDate is older than the endDate, it will return `0`, which works perfectly on some cases. Also, if the two dates are the same, it will return 0. It also returns a plain integer. Other answers have to be transformed into integers or you may have to translate to 0 if the result is negative.

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me:

```
(endDate - beginDate).to_i
```

Answer (score 7):

all of these steered me to the correct result, but I wound up doing

```
DateTime.now.mjd - DateTime.parse("01-01-1995").mjd
```

Comment: One tidbit to point out: DateTime.parse in Ruby expects the date to be given as DD/MM/YYYY, or DD-MM-YYYY. As an American, it always throws me off!

Comment: @rickumali As a member from the rest of the world, I thank Ruby for using "our" default date format.

Comment: @rickumali Ruby accepts the date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format as well, which is what everyone should be using anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
num_days = later_date - earlier_date
```

Answer (score 2):

days = (endDate - beginDate)/(60*60*24)

Comment: Date is in terms of days, so you don't need to do this. I think your solution becomes relevant with DateTime differences.

Answer (score 1):

Well, take care of what you mean by "between" too...

```rb
days_apart = (to - from).to_i     # from + days_apart = to
total_days = (to - from).to_i + 1 # number of "selected" days
in_between_days = (to - from).to_i - 1 # how many days are in between from and to, i.e. excluding those two days
```