# Date subtraction in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, date

I have a class that has two params: `start_date` and `end_date`.

Those are formatted like - 2012-07-12 and 2012-07-24.

I was to subtract `end_date` from `start_date`.

Previous Googling has left me high and dry. Should I convert these to something else to do subtraction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert them into dates and subtract them:

```
require 'date'

start_date = Date.parse('2012-07-12')
end_date = Date.parse('2012-07-24')

(start_date - end_date).to_i

=> -12
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of days `(end_date-start_date).days` should work fine. You'll probably get a `Rational` number of days, in which case you can just use `to_i`

Answer (score 0):

If i am not miskaten, the params come in form of a `String`, so you have to convert it to a `Date`, `DateTime`, or `Time` to do math operations with them.
You can refer to this question to more details.
[How can I find the number of days between two Date objects in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502245/number-of-days-between-two-date-objects-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

You can just substract two DateTime objects

Using 1.9

```
require 'date'
DateTime.parse(end_date) - DateTime.parse(start_date)
```