# Method to render how many days remain in membership - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently I have method called `expiration_date` that calls the created_at and adds 1 year to that date. I now would like to make a method that says essentially how many days are left until it is `expiration_date` and call that on the view. I'll show my Model code for clarity and hopefully this will make more sense.

MODEL

```
class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :phone_number, presence: true

  def date_joined
   created_at.strftime("%-m/%-d/%-y")
  end

  def expiration_date
   (created_at + 1.year).strftime("%-m/%-d/%-y")
  end

  def days_till_expired
    #code
  end
end
```

CONTROLLER

```
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @subscriber = Subscriber.all
  end

  def new
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new
  end

  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.create(subscriber_params)
    if @subscriber.save
      flash[:notice] = "Subscriber Has Been Successfully Created"
      redirect_to new_subscriber_path(:subscriber)
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def search
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new
  end

  def visit
    @subscriber = Subscriber.find_by_phone_number(params[:phone_number])
    if @subscriber
      @subscriber.visit =+ 1
      @subscriber.save
      redirect_to subscribers_search_path(:subscriber)
    else
      render "search"
    end
  end
end
```

I have a view form where a user will type in their phone_number and it will flash a notice to aware them how much time they have left. I think that I will need to grab the user params of their phone number when it's sent in. does this make sense?

Comment: check out this gem: https://github.com/tmlee/time_difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
def days_till_expiration
  ((created_at + 1.year) - DateTime.now).to_i / 1.day
end
```

Comment: This works great but its a float datatype. Do you know how I can change it to a int?

Comment: Updated above... Change if you want to round differently

Comment: FYI, I don't think you should use the expiration date to be dependent on creation date. It should be a field in the database that you probably assign the first time. You can update this method accordingly =)

Comment: Thank @Abdo! just to be clear, the expiration date should be its on field?

Comment: @CameronBass certainly. You want to be able to extend it later, no? So it must have its own field :-)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you just want to take the number of days between `created_at + 1.year` and today's date (that you can have by doing `Date.today`). If you make `date1 - date2` it returns the number of days between date1 and date2.

Please note that (as mentionned here [How can I find the number of days between two Date objects in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502245/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-days-between-two-date-objects-in-ruby)), since Ruby 2.1.3, the difference of dates returns a Rational. So you get `(5/1)` instead of `5`. To solve this, just use `to_i`. If you are using a version of Ruby older than 2.1.3 you should be able to remove `to_i`. Overall we get :

```
 def days_till_expired
    (created_at + 1.year - Date.today).to_i
 end
```

You might have to use `require 'date'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `gem time_diff` :
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/time_diff/0.3.0

Without using any external gem, you can easily get differences between dates using a method like this:

```
def days_till_expired
   delta = created_at + 1.year - Date.today
   %w[days].collect do |step|
      days = 1.send(step)
      (delta / days).to_i.tap do
          delta %= days
      end
   end
end
```