# Rails datetime comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time

My application offers the opportunity to create events with a start date and an end date with a certain format. Events should not last longer than two weeks, so the events controller check this condition with a `before_action`:

```
def correct_time
  @event = current_user.events.build(event_params)
  if (@event.end_time.to_datetime - @event.start_time.to_datetime) > 2.weeks
    flash[:danger] = "Attention! Events cannot last longer than 2 weeks"
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

So I was puzzled when I was able to create the following event, which lasts 22 days:

```
>> event = Event.last
=> #<Event id: 1, user_id: 1, place: "barcelona", start_time: "2017-12-24 10:26", end_time: "2018-01-15 10:26", created_at: "2017-12-15 09:27:13", updated_at: "2017-12-15 09:27:13">
```

Apparently the condition does not work because Rails mistakes days with seconds:

```
>> (event.end_time.to_datetime - event.start_time.to_datetime)
=> (22/1)

>> (event.end_time.to_date - event.start_time.to_date) > 2.weeks
=> false

>> (event.end_time.to_datetime - event.start_time.to_datetime) == 22.days
=> false

>> (event.end_time.to_datetime - event.start_time.to_datetime) == 22.seconds
=> true
```

I do not know why this happens and how to solve it, apart from using `14.seconds` instead of `2.weeks` in the above expression, but that would not be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use the integer, without the `.days`?

```
(event.end_time.to_date - event.start_time.to_date) == 22 # => true
```

Or convert to time objects:

```
(@event.end_time.to_time - @event.start_time.to_time) > 2.weeks
```

There are tons of possibilities to count the number of days between two dates, but the comparison has to be made using an integer:

```
(event.start_time.to_date..event.end_time.to_date).count > 14
```

see [How can I find the number of days between two Date objects in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502245/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-days-between-two-date-objects-in-ruby)

Comment: Thanks, I can do that, however I still do not know why Rails considers that integer being seconds instead of days

Comment: `22.days` creates an instance of a Duration http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#method-i-days, which itself uses seconds internally to represent the duration http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html

Comment: However 22 are days, not seconds. `22.days == (86400 x 22).seconds`. If the duraton is in seconds, the result should be 1900800, not 22, imho, as far as I understand.

Comment: You have to be careful what you subtract from another. If you subtract `Date` you get a difference in days. If you subtract `Time`s you get seconds.

Comment: Understood. I suppose that it is more correct use `to_time` instead of `to_date` or `to_datetime.`

Comment: it depends :-) sometimes you do not need the granularity of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the event duration as below:

```
if (@event.end_time.to_datetime - @event.start_time.to_datetime).to_i > 14
  flash[:danger] = "Attention! Events cannot last longer than 2 weeks"
  redirect_to root_url
end
```