# Calculate the cost of a reservation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a reservation application which allows the user to reserve a vehicle. I've listed the cost of the hire per day on the vehicle ie £100 a day. How do I calculate the total cost of the hire?

On the reservation new (_form.html.erb) 
the user selects a start date and a end date

```
 <div class="field">
  <%= form.label :startDate, "Start Date:" %>
  <%= form.text_field :startDate, {class: "form-control custom", id: "start-date"}%> 
 </div>

 <div class="field">
  <%= form.label :endDate, "End Date:" %>
  <%= form.text_field :endDate, {class: "form-control custom", id: "end-date"}%> 
 </div>
```

currently the cost field is the default input field.

I can call the vehicle cost using

```
<%= @vehicle.cost %>
```

How would I calculate the cost? 
Will it be something along the lines of endDate - startDate to get total days and then multiplying it with the cost?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502245/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-days-between-two-date-objects-in-ruby

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find the number of days between two Date objects in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502245/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-days-between-two-date-objects-in-ruby)

Comment: would I do this in my rb or the views? I also want to be able to multiple the number of days by the cost to get a total cost of the reservation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total cost is the daily price * number of days.

**If you want to calculate the price in the controller:**

```
start = Date.parse(params[:startDate])
end = Date.parse(params[:endDate])
price = @vehicle.cost * (end - start).to_i
```

**If you want to do it in the view, while changing dates:**

```
<span id="daily-price" style="display:none"><%= @vehicle.price %></span>
<div id="full-price"></div>

<script>
  $( "#start-date, #end-date" ).change(function() {
    var d1=document.getElementById("start-date").value;
    var d2=document.getElementById("end-date").value;
    var start = new Date(d1);
    var end = new Date(d2);
    var daily_price=document.getElementById("daily-price").innerHTML;

    var full_price = daily_price * (end-start) / (24*3600*1000); // from milliseconds to days.
    $("#full-price").innerHTML=full_price;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the above. I'm trying to use the one in the views while changing dates. I've got vehicle cost on the previous page. I've tried calling the vehicle cost like `var daily_price=document.getElementById(<%= @vehicle.price %>).value;` this does't work. what would be the best way?

Comment: You should include vehicle cost in this page (it can be a hidden field). Or you can use a data-attribute in the full-price field to hold the daily price.

Comment: i can call it on the view like`<%= @vehicle.price %>` but I don't know how to call it in the java bit. i've attempted to give it a "id: "daily-price"`

Comment: I updated my answer to include a field with the price.

Comment: Sorry but it just will not work. I can't see it updating or do anything. I can see how you're setting daily price and so on. I just can't figure out why its not working. any suggestions?

Comment: The script must be inside <script> ... </script>. Add some alert messages in the script to check if it is been called and price is calculated ok.

Comment: I've done this. Another thing if i try to save the reservation even though I can't see a calculated price the "price" for `<%= @vehicle.price %>` gives an error message  "undefined method `price' for nil:NilClass" this doesn't come if the on JavaScript to calculate the cost isn't there

Comment: Sorry the above is unrelated, I've fixed that issue. still investigating the calculation

Comment: Hi, after trying to debug, i believe putting the `<%= @vehicle.price %>` is span tags is not working as intended. I've used the following in JavaScript to try and get the one day cost and it shows "undefined" in the cost input field. The code I've put in my JavaScript is `<script type="text/javascript">
    var daily_price=document.getElementById('daily-price').value;
    document.getElementById('full-price').value = (daily_price) ;
</script>`

Comment: Try with innerHTML instead of value.

Comment: okay that's now displaying the cost. I'll try using your solution hopefully it'll work now.