# Subtracting dates in ruby or rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following:

```
due_date = Date.parse '2020-07-18 00:00:00 -0700'
today_date = Time.now
(due_date - today_date).to_i
```

I start out by converting the date string (this is a string, not an ActiveRecord datetime object), into a date object.

Then I create a new date object using Time.now, but when I try to subtract, I get an error:

(note that I am running this inside a Rails console):

```
irb(main):001:0>     due_date = Date.parse '2020-07-18 00:00:00 -0700'
=> Sat, 18 Jul 2020
irb(main):002:0>     today_date = Time.now
=> 2020-04-22 17:39:17 -0700
irb(main):003:0>     (due_date - today_date).to_i
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from (irb):3
TypeError (expected numeric)
```

I thought I can subtract the two date object to come up with difference in days. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find the number of days between two Date objects in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502245/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-days-between-two-date-objects-in-ruby)

Comment: No, but the answer provided by elilitt works

Comment: Cool! Glad it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date and Time are not the same class so you can't just subtract one from the other.

Try using DateTime instead or coercing time into a date using `to_date`.

```
due_date = DateTime.parse '2020-07-18 00:00:00 -0700'
today_date = DateTime.current
(due_date - today_date).to_i
```

Also be careful using Time.now because it's not time zone aware (https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones)

Comment: This fixes the problem. Thank you, and thanks for the tip about Time.now