# calculating age method with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to create a method that calculates the age and I can do it by the year but how can do it exactly by day, month and year?

If i simply do today - birthday I get 12535/1

```
require 'date'

def age_in_days(day, month, year)
   birthdate = Date.new(year, month, day)
   today  = Date.today

   age = today.year - birthdate.year

   return birthdate, today, age
end

puts age_in_days(12, 10, 1990)
```

Comment: For calculating the difference in days, have you had a look at the Modified Julian Day Number? e.g `today.mjd - birthdate.mjd` Check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4502336/1611339

Comment: I don't understand your question. I was born on 12-Feb-1915. If today's date were 13-Mar-2020, would the answer be 105 years, 1 month and 1 day, or something else? If the latter, you need to be precise in describing what you want.

Comment: Note: In Ruby you don't need an explicit `return`, instead you can do `[ birthdate, today, age ]`.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the difference considering the day month and year you can use the following approach.

```
require 'date'

def age_in_years(day, month, year)   
  birthdate = Time.new(year, month, day)
  avg_seconds_in_year = 31557600
  seconds = (Time.now- birthdate).to_i
  years = seconds/avg_seconds_in_year
  years
end

puts age_in_years(12, 10, 1990)
```

will output `29`.

This answer depends on the fact that a year has, on average, 365.25 days, this is 31557600 seconds.

Now In the method you can see the `seconds` represents the difference in seconds. Now from there you can calculate the year(like i did by dividing by 31557600). you can calculate the difference in months, days, hours, minutes, seconds as well.

If you want to make the function return the age in days, hours, minutes and seconds then the following will do that :

```
require 'date'

def age_in_days(day, month, year) 
  birthdate = Time.new(year, month, day)
  seconds = (Time.now- birthdate).to_i
  mm, ss = seconds.divmod(60)
  hh, mm = mm.divmod(60)
  dd, hh = hh.divmod(24)
  "#{dd} days, #{hh} hours, #{mm} minutes and #{ss} seconds"
end

puts age_in_days(12, 10, 1990)
```

will output `10845 days, 14 hours, 41 minutes and 55 seconds`.